# Javascript function only receive integers

Tags: javascript, php

I call for a java script function and send 4 parameters with it, it only works if there are only  integers send for the 4th parameter.
Here is my `onchange` function:

```
onchange="weekchange(this, <?php echo $i ?>,<?php echo $teller ?>,<?php echo $project[$i] ?>)"
```

When I call this function I send 4 parameters with it: this, $i, $teller and $project[$i].

When $project[$i] is only integers my java script function will accept it. This variable is the name of a project, this name can have numbers, letters and characters like !@#$%^& in it. When I have a project name that has a character that has a letter or characters like !@#$%^& in it, it doesn't do anything. Also when I only have integers and it starts with a 0 i get very weird results. 01234 ends up being 668?

My java script function:

```
function weekchange(selected, weekkeuze, aantalprojecten, projectnaam)
{
var samen;
var week;
var id;
var projecten = String(projectnaam);
alert(selected.value);
week  = selected.value;
id = weekkeuze;
samen = "id="+id+"&week="+week+"&projectnaam="+projecten;
var test = document.getElementById(id)
test = test+1;

submit_javascript("GET","capaciteitberekening.php?"+samen+"&dag="+0,id+"ma","true");
submit_javascript("GET","capaciteitberekening.php?"+samen+"&dag="+1,id+"di","true");
submit_javascript("GET","capaciteitberekening.php?"+samen+"&dag="+2,id+"wo","true");
submit_javascript("GET","capaciteitberekening.php?"+samen+"&dag="+3,id+"do","true");
submit_javascript("GET","capaciteitberekening.php?"+samen+"&dag="+4,id+"vr","true");
}
```

How is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in JavaScript must be in quotes; a handy way to output a string to the JavaScript layer is to use `json_encode` (which is happy to output JSON fragments, not just entire JSON documents). Quotes in attribute values (like `onchange`) should be marked up as HTML entities, so we can use `htmlspecialchars` to handle the output of `json_encode`. So:

```
onchange="weekchange(this, <?php echo $i ?>,<?php echo $teller ?>,<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($project[$i])) ?>)"
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the PHP tags to dynamically define part of the HTML on the server, but when it reaches the browser it's going to be plain old regular JavaScript inside an element's `onchange` attribute. So your code

```
onchange="weekchange(this, <?php echo $i ?>,<?php echo $teller ?>,<?php echo $project[$i] ?>)"
```

might result in a bit of HTML that looks like this:

```
onchange="weekchange(this, 1,some text,project 1234)"
```

That's not valid JavaScript, because `project 1234` doesn't mean anything in JavaScript. Even without the spaces in there, `project1234`, would mean that it needs to pass the value of a JavaScript variable called `project1234` to the function, rather than passing the literal value `project1234`.

You'll need to wrap any arguments you're generating from PHP in quotes, either single or double, like so:

```
onchange="weekchange(this, '<?php echo $i ?>','<?php echo $teller ?>','<?php echo $project[$i] ?>')"
```